# fread not returning error on closed file in C

Tags: c, fread, fclose

From my understanding fread should not be able to read a file after said file has been closed with fclose. However, when running this code

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){`

    File *fid;
    int test;
    char buf_read [5];
    
    fid = fopen("test.txt", "rb");
    fclose(fid);
    test = fread(buf_read, 1, 5, fid);
    fprintf(stdout, "%d \n", test);
}
```

it prints 5, when with my understanding of how fread works it should print 0 as fread should not be able  to read from a closed file. is there some functionality with fread or fclose that I am missing here?

Comment: You're can't possibly compile successfully.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: He just keyed it in manually when he should have copy/pasted. No matter, the reason for the problem is easily found. Next time it might not be so easy though.

Answer (score 0):

From the [`fclose` man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fclose.3.html):

> any further access (including another call to fclose()) to the stream results in undefined behavior.

You're invoking undefined behavior; anything can happen, including seemingly-correct behavior like you're experiencing.

The best thing you can do is set the stream (`fid`) to `NULL` immediately after calling `fclose`.

Comment: ok, can I expect errno to be set then even if fread is returning 5 if I call ferror on the closed file pointer?

Comment: @ColeHavener: When you invoke undefined behavior, you cannot expect anything at all.  You certainly cannot be assured of having `errno` set.  On some systems you may get a segfault, or a successful return and random memory corruption.